# Unicode Error when running Flake8 test with TOX

Tags: python, tox, flake8

I'm new to Tox and i want to set it up to run flake8 test on my project but i keep getting unicode error when i try to run tox.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 76: ordinal not in range(128)`

This is a peek of my tox.ini file:

```
[tox]
envlist = flake8

[testenv:flake8]
basepython = python2
skip_install = true
deps =
    flake8
commands =
    flake8 -v

# Flake8 Configuration
[flake8]
# Ignore some flake8-docstrings errors
# NOTE(sigmavirus24): While we're still using flake8 2.x, this ignore line
# defaults to selecting all other errors so we do not need select=E,F,W,I,D
# Once Flake8 3.0 is released and in a good state, we can use both and it will
# work well \o/
ignore = D203, E226, E302, E41
exclude =
    .tox,
    .git,
    __pycache__,
    build,
    dist,
    *.pyc,
    *.egg-info,
    .cache,
    .eggs
max-complexity = 10
import-order-style = google
application-import-names = flake8
```

Comment: what is the output of `echo $LANG` from terminal? Which version of tox are you using?

Comment: @RaviKumar The output of `echo $LANG` is empty. I make use of Tox 2.7.0

Comment: Can you test after writing `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in terminal?

Comment: Hey @RaviKumar, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tox reads environment variables to get encoding information for your language.

You cant set it in terminal. (Write in .bashrc file to make it permanent)

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

or pass it in tox.ini file

```
setenv = LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```