# How to fix 'UnicodeDecodeError' in 'envreport' when running tox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tox

I want to use tox to automate testing of my python package. As of now, just locally. When running tox, the test passes, but then a UnicodeDecodeError is thrown. `tox --version` is 3.13.2.

The error message (full traceback below):

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 70: invalid continuation byte`

The tests succeed when running `tox`,  which is visualize with `-vvvvvv`, which I expect. The functions do not do anything and are just a dummy at the moment (Automatically created using the cookiecutter-pypackage). I reduced the items in the envlist to just py37. Anaconda is in my `PATH` variable and no regular python is installed. I tried using different python versions by writing a .bat (i am using Windows) like on the official tox documentation. This works identically to the py37. Test pass and the following is thrown.

I could not find anything in the [tox documentation](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) regarding `UnicodeDecodeErrors`.

Neither powershell or my commandline can execute `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384822/unicode-error-when-running-flake8-test-with-tox) post. Setting `setenv = LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in the `tox.ini` also did not change anything.

The Traceback below is for the `py37` environment, which gets called when adding `skipdist = true` to `tox.ini`. Leaving that out will still return the exact same error, with an almost identical traceback.

The error is thrown from `codecy.py` file. Moving up in the Traceback and looking into each file didn't help me, as i could not find out, which file gets encoded or anything else, which could help. Without posting the whole console output with the successful virtualenv creation, something could help. The Error is thrown on the `envreport` in the summary. `tox-envreport` is not installed if that matters. When the sdist gets tested, it is in the `GLOB sdist-make:` section.

```
py37 finish: finishvenv  after 0.02 seconds
py37 start: envreport
setting PATH=C:\Users\cosmo\OneDrive - Universität zu Köln\package\.tox\py37\Scripts;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Users\cosmo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\cosmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\cosmo\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3;.
[7836] C:\Users\cosmo\OneDrive - Universität zu Köln\package$ 'C:\Users\cosmo\OneDrive - Universität zu Köln\package\.tox\py37\Scripts\python.EXE' -m pip freeze >.tox\py37\log\py37-0.log
_________________________________________________________________________ summary __________________________________________________________________________
  py37: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\cosmo\Anaconda3\Scripts\tox.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\session\__init__.py", line 44, in cmdline
    main(args)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\session\__init__.py", line 68, in main
    exit_code = session.runcommand()
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\session\__init__.py", line 192, in runcommand
    return self.subcommand_test()
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\session\__init__.py", line 220, in subcommand_test
    run_sequential(self.config, self.venv_dict)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\session\commands\run\sequential.py", line 20, in run_sequential
    runenvreport(venv, config)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\session\commands\run\sequential.py", line 60, in runenvreport
    packages = config.pluginmanager.hook.tox_runenvreport(venv=venv, action=action)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 289, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\venv.py", line 780, in tox_runenvreport
    output = venv._pcall(args, cwd=venv.envconfig.config.toxinidir, action=action, returnout=True)
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\venv.py", line 574, in _pcall
    report_fail=not is_test_command,
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tox\action.py", line 107, in popen
    lines = out_path.read_text("UTF-8").split("\n")
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py", line 165, in read_text
    return f.read()
  File "c:\users\cosmo\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 70: invalid continuation byte
```

My question:

- How can i fix this?
- What file may be the reason for this (seemingly bad enconding)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess.
Place your application outside this folder: OneDrive - Universität zu Köln
The problem in Köln I think.

This is good traceback to feel tox bug report.

Comment: I'm german and didn't even think of it being an issue. The 'ö' is part of [UTF-8](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) and i am still not sure, why this problem occurs. The issue was in the path, not any file.

Comment: It is interesting to test same path in linux environment. As far as i remember windows systems has some problems with some symbols in UTF-8, bacause microsoft use own UTF-8 implementation. This topic was part of Pycon 2019 in Cleveland.

You can check youtube for video called something like python in windows is ok. Something like this. From Pycon Cleveland 2019

Comment: Here is the link to the talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoI57uMdDD4